# laravel return two meged response

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my laravel projrct that uses another function to send otp sms, but when I run the second function, and after return the response ,laravel return a merged response: first one is response of the second function and another one is my custom response,
my code is here:

```
$otp=rand(12345,99999);
            
             VerificationCode::create([
                'mobile'=>$mobile,
                'otp'=>$otp,
                'expire_at'=>Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)

            ]);
            $this->sendSms($otp,$mobile);
            return response([
        'result'=>'verificationCode has sent',
        'message'=>'ok',
        'status'=>'200'
    ]);
```

and second function is:

```
public function sendSms($otp,$mobile){    
$post_data = http_build_query($data);
        $handle = curl_init('https://example.com/api/SendSMS/BaseServiceNumber');
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ));
        // curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
       $response= curl_exec($handle);
        curl_close($handle);
        return $response;
}
```

the returned response is:

```
{"Value":"5589489218988866748","RetStatus":1,"StrRetStatus":"Ok"}{"result":null,"message":"ok","status":"200"}
```

why this part (`{"Value":"558948925522554445","RetStatus":1,"StrRetStatus":"Ok"}`) is added to the initial of the response?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);` line in the `sendSms` function. When you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `false`, the `curl_exec` function directly outputs the response instead of returning it as a string. This causes the response from the SMS API to be sent directly to the output, and then your custom response is appended to it.

To fix this issue, change the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to `true`:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This will make `curl_exec` return the response as a string, which you can then store in the `$response` variable. Since you're not using the `$response` variable in your main function, you can remove the `return $response;` line from the `sendSms` function.

```
$post_data = http_build_query($data);
$handle = curl_init('https://example.com/api/SendSMS/BaseServiceNumber');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Change this line
$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
// Remove the return statement
```

Now, when you call the `sendSms` function, it won't output the SMS API response directly, and you should only see your custom response in the output.

Comment: Tnx. curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  solved the problem. Removing the return statement is not needed